# Dynamic div creation for dc.js and implementing crossfiltered dashboard

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am creating a generic dashboard where you upload any data -- with any number of columns, one should be able to visualize the bar charts dynamically using dc.js. 
Till now, I had been creating individual div element for each column (when file column types and count is known). What should I do to make the div creation automatic as per the number of columns of csv file uploaded sothat  the charts are created accordingly with crossfilter enabled ?

Note: Generic means the file can have any number of columns and all should be bar charts. What I want is -- According to the number of columns, it should create dynamically the bar charts as we implement in dc.js(crossfiltered feature -- creating dimensions and group according to the number of columns in the csv file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would usually just generate the divs with d3:

```
var cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'];
var divs = d3.selectAll('div.yourchart').data(cols);
divs.enter().append('div').attr('class', 'yourchart');

var dcCharts = new Array(cols.length);
divs.each(function(col, i) {
  var dimension = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d[col]; });
  var group = dimension.group(); // or however you want to bin them
  var bar = dc.barChart(this) // pass div element as parent/root instead of using selector
      .dimension(dimension)
      .group(group)
      // ...
  dcCharts[i] = bar;
});
```

dc.js charts can be constructed given a parent/root *element* instead of a selector, useful here.

Comment: I dont understand what is 'yourchart' for ? I see that is a class, I donot understand it completely. If possible please help me understand with a demo jsfiddle, or a related work.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I wasn't really offering to write this for you, was just trying point you in the right direction. `yourclass` is any unique class name for the purpose of identifying the divs so that the d3 [general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) knows what to add/update/remove. I corrected one typo above. My point is that there's no magic, you just create divs, and when you initialize the charts, you pass the element instead of the selector.

Comment: Hi, I used your advice exactly as you said. I never made any chart with id dc-chart1 Can you please help me solve the error "Mandatory attribute chart.x is missing on chart[#dc-chart1]"

Comment: The error means that you need to specify `.x(...)` when defining your chart. What `...` should be depends on your data. I didn't give a full chart definition above - you need to look at your previous code, and examples on the web, to figure out how to define your charts.

Comment: I figured out. I could do it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Hey, I am stuck at a point. dcCharts  = d3.selectAll("div.mychart") 
            .attr("class", "yourchart") 
            .each(function (d, i) { 
            return d ; 
         });

Comment: Are you trying to get an array of the charts? I'd imperatively build the array during initialization - I've edited my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707557/on-function-for-dc-js-charts-showing-error Just added a question separately

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I was not able to put the question in the comment, please check my full problem in the above query. Thanks for helping out beginners like me.