# .on function for dc.js charts showing error

Tags: dc.js

I am stuck at a point

```
dcCharts  = d3.selectAll("div.mychart") 
            .attr("class", "yourchart") 
            .each(function (d, i) { 
            return d ; 
         });
```

I retrieve the divs and do this:
`

```
 _.each(dcCharts, function (dcChart) {
    dcChart.on("filtered", function (chart, filter) {
        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        map.removeLayer(layer)
        }); 
    drawMap();
    });
    dc.renderAll();
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: dcChart.on is not a function
    at updateFile:229
    at Function.m.each.m.forEach (underscore-min.js:5)
    at updateFile:228
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.v3.js:1996)
    at Object.event (d3.v3.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.respond (d3.v3.js:1949)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, this is a follow-up to [Dynamic div creation for dc.js and implementing crossfiltered dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327014/dynamic-div-creation-for-dc-js-and-implementing-crossfiltered-dashboard) which provides some context.

The issue here is that the bound data for each `div` is the string column name, not the chart. If you want to produce an array of charts, I recommend building the array while initializing the charts. (copied from my edited answer to the previous question)

```
var dcCharts = new Array(cols.length);
divs.each(function(col, i) {
  var dimension = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d[col]; });
  var group = dimension.group(); // or however you want to bin them
  var bar = dc.barChart(this) // pass div element as parent/root instead of using selector
      .dimension(dimension)
      .group(group)
      // ...
  dcCharts[i] = bar;
});
```

Now your `_.each(dcCharts, ...` should work.

Comment: I am getting the same error. I tried print what does dcCharts look like. Got this: `Array(4)
ƒ axis(g)
ƒ axis(g)
ƒ axis(g)
ƒ axis(g)`

Comment: When you modify the axes of a dc chart, you should do it in a separate line, [because from that point it will be the axis returned, not the chart](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis).

Comment: Yes, exactly. I did not know that. Thanks a lot for formatting my questions, I will make sure I frame it well from next time. Thanks a ton for all the help, had a great learning time working with dc.js.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I am trying to name each of the chart by iterating through the column names. Is there a way to show the chart names? 'title' attribute seems to be the tooltip feature.

Comment: No, there's usually no need because you can just add an  `<h3>` element (or whatever you like) before each div or inside the div. That way it's easier to match the style of the rest of the page too.

Comment: Yes, got it that way. Thanks